# Derivation of Conditional Causal Probabilities

Tags: conditional-probability, causality, graphical-model

In [Causal Inference in Statistics: an Overview](https://ftp.cs.ucla.edu/pub/stat_ser/r350.pdf), Pearl presents an equation describing distribution from a graphical model presented in figure 3:

---

[image]

The author arrives at equality (20) - see image above. This is fine, I understand this. However, later on , the author derives equation (23):

---

[image]

I cannot seem to get that, here is my shot at the problem:
$
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
P(y |do(x_0)) &= \sum_{z_1,z_2,z_3} P(z_1) P(z_2) P(z_3 |z_1,z_2) P(y |z_2,z_3,x_0) \text{ equation (20)}\\
&=\sum P(z_1) P(z_3,z_2 |z_1) P(y |z_2,z_3,x_0) \text{ since $z_2 \perp z_1$}\\
&=\sum_{z_1,z_2,z_3} P(z_1) P(y,z_2,z_3 |x_0,z_1) \text{ not sure why}\\
&=\sum_{z_1,z_2,z_3} P(z_1)  P(y,z_3 |x_0, z_1) \text{ marginalize over $z_2$}\\
&=\sum_{z_1,z_2,z_3} P(z_1)  P(y|z_1,z_3,x_0)P(z_3|z_1,x_0) \text{ cond. probability} \\
&= \sum_{z_1,z_3} P(z_1) P(z_3 |z_1) P(y |z_1,z_3,x_0) \text{ I doubt this step is correct}
\end{split}
\end{align}
$

Answer (score 1):

There is a more straightforward way to derive the total causal effect to be $P(y|do(x))=\sum\limits_{z_1,z_3}P(Z_1=z_1)P(Z_3=z_3|Z_1=z_1)P(Y=y|Z_1=z_1,Z_3=z_3,X=x)$

Because the set {$Z_1,Z_3$} satisfies the backdoor criterion, we can get the causal effect of $X$ on $Y$ by conditionalizing the conditional probability $P(Y=y|X=x)$ on the set {$Z_1,Z_3$} (in the book "Causal Inference in Statistics: A Primer" he calls this the ***adjustment rule***):
$$P(Y=y|do(X=x))=\sum\limits_{z_1,z_3}P(Y=y|X=x,Z_1=z_1,Z_3=z_3)P(Z_1=z_1,Z_3=z_3)$$
As a last step, we use the causal graph to express $P(Z_1=z_1,Z_3=z_3)$ as $P(Z_1=z_1)P(Z_3=z_3|Z_1=z_1)$ and we arrive at the desired expression:

$P(y|do(x))=\sum\limits_{z_1,z_3}P(Z_1=z_1)P(Z_3=z_3|Z_1=z_1)P(Y=y|Z_1=z_1,Z_3=z_3,X=x)$